# How to do sudo -i by java while running on windows

Tags: sudo

I am writing my code in eclipse on windows and i need to connect to a unix box and do sudo -i and thereafter run some shell commands.

I am able to create a unix session using jsch but am unable to perform the command "sudo -i". Can some one let me know how to do it.

When i google then most of the results suggest to use "Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo -i")" but this command will look for the processes on the windows and not on the unix session.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

- the sudo thing must go *into* the command you are sending to the remote site. But of course sudo will then ask for the password which makes things really complicated.
- thus: it is often much easier to simply connect as *root* user directly. Meaning: don't log in as normal user and then run sudo - log in as root initially.

Of course, the later is sometimes not possible because remote login is disabled for the root account.

Comment: System.out.println("Entered the username and password");

  session.connect();
  System.out.println("Session Connected SUccessfully");
 
  
  ChannelExec channel=(ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
  
  BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(channel.getInputStream()));
   
  channel.setCommand(" sudo -i pwd");
  
  channel.connect();

Comment: Add this to your question instead of putting things into comments. And; it simply isn't that simple. Sudo expects a command name to execute with root rights. The password is not a command.

Comment: adding this one worked   channel.setCommand("sudo su - root -c \"pwd\";");

Comment: Glad to hear that you found a solution. If you think my answer helped getting there please consider accepting or at least upvoting. Otherwise you might consider deleting the whole question.